# Java.Net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am sending a data to my server via JSON Object I am using VPN to connect to my server. I am getting a **Java.Net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET**. What are the possible causes and fixes of this? I am using PHP to insert the data to my database. My VPN is Sonic Wall.

Stack Trace:
[image: Stack Trace]

My Code:

```
 try{
    syncStatus.Text = "Sending retailer outlet changes to server " + count + " out of " + changesresultCount;

    var crresult = getContactsChanges.Result[i];
    var crcontactID = crresult.ContactID;
    var crfileAs = crresult.FileAs;
    var crfirstName = crresult.FirstName;
    var crmiddleName = crresult.MiddleName;
    var crlastName = crresult.LastName;

    var crlink = "http://" + ipaddress + Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=nLm8YE";
    string crcontentType = "application/json";
    JObject crjson = new JObject
    {
        { "ContactID", crcontactID },
        { "FileAs", crfileAs },
        { "FirstName", crfirstName },
        { "MiddleName", crmiddleName },
        { "LastName", crlastName },
    };

    HttpClient crclient = new HttpClient();
    var crresponse = await crclient.PostAsync(crlink, new StringContent(crjson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, crcontentType));

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
}
```

Comment: The error stack trace would help, also if possible tell us where it crashes!

Comment: @G.hakim I added the stack trace

Comment: Crashes on `await crclient.PostAsync`?

Comment: @G.hakim yes what are the causes of this error

Comment: Did you try hitting this API from postman/fiddler and checked whether it works?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes I tried and it works. The problem is 
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort when sending data to my server

Comment: Of course you have the internet permission in your manifest!

Comment: @G.hakim Do I need to remove the internet permission in my manifest?

Comment: Of course not if you remove that it would be a huge problem i was just making sure you had it, it is needed for socket initialization

Comment: Are you aware about what `ECONNRESET`?

Comment: @G.hakim no sorry can you elaborate?